# How can I record Best Service Engine Celtic Era on Ableton? Nothing works so far

Tags: ableton-live

How can I record in Ableton with the Best Service Engine Celtic Era and Dark Era kit? No matter what I try I cannot get it to record sound from my computer. None of the tutorials on youtube are working. Loading the kits VST files into my plugin folder did nothing. The kits are .ytil files. I think you can get it on Cubase, but everything is already so expensive, I do not want to have to buy that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the Era kits from Best Service must be ran through Magix Samplitude. They will not work on any other platform I believe.